# How to calculate probability of being with in one standard deviation of the mean value for a continuous distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, continuity, standard-deviation

for a pdf of $f(x) = 90x^8(1-x)$, $0 < x < 1$, otherwise $f(x)=0$

I have calculated a  of $F(x) = 10x^9 -9x^{10}$ for $0 < x < 1$

a mean of $9/11$

and a standard deviation of $\sqrt{.0123}$

I'm having a tough time figuring out what the  $\mathbb P(A < x < B)$ would be, and if I use the integral of the pdf or the cdf to calculate said probability.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

$$\mathbb P(A < x < B) = \mathbb P(x < B) - \mathbb P(x \le A) = F(B) - F(A)$$

Comment: so I would be calculating P( x <= 9/11+sqrt(.0123)) - P(( x <= 9/11-sqrt(.0123)), correct?

Comment: @user1809295 it depends on what are $A$ and $B$, if $B= 9/11 + \sqrt{.0123}$, and $A=9/11-\sqrt{.0123}$, then YES. I guess you meant $A,B$ to be values one standard deviation away from mean, right? If that's is the case, yes.